# Dynamically adjusting number in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I maintain an in stock count in our application but each day I want to overwrite that number with the in stock count on the stock list that comes from our supplier.

The problem that I have is that the application that I use requires an adjustment rather than just setting what the new in stock count should be.

```
my_available = 10
supplier_available = 0
adjustment = -10

my_available = 0
supplier_available = 10
adjustment = +10

my_available = -10
supplier_available = 0
adjustment = +10
```

How can I calculate the `adjustment` in Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

try: `adjustment = supplier_available - my_available`

This will yield the correct result for the samples you gave:

```
my_available = 10
supplier_available = 0
adjustment = -10 # => 0 - 10

my_available = 0
supplier_available = 10
adjustment = +10 # => 10 - 0

my_available = -10
supplier_available = 0
adjustment = +10 # => 0 - -10
```

Note that `+10` and `10` is the same (`+10 == 10 => true`) so you can drop the sign for positive numbers.

Answer (score -1):

not sure if I clearly understand the question but have you tried something like the example below?

```
my_available = -10
supplier_available = 0
a = supplier_available - my_available
adjustment = if a>0
               a = '+'+a
             else
               a
              end
```

Comment: I don't think he wants a string.

Comment: @pascalbetz `adjustment = +10` in question for sure is a string

Comment: I don't think so. I think it was added for clarity (though it might confuse programmers :-))